# angular 2 distance from top on scroll based on id

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am using angular 2 for one of my projects .I have 3 tables whose heights are unknown ie it can be growing.Now on scroll,i want to know if the top of the element has passed the top navbar ie if the first table is scrolled and second is visible,i need to initialize a variable so that i can do further operations.I tried using viewchild as

```
@ViewChild('leaveApproval') element:ElementRef;
console.log(this.element.nativeElement.topOffset);
```

and in the html

```
  <div class="twelve wide right floated column" #leaveApproval>
```

but console.log always  returns "undefined".How do i solve this problem or how to go about this

Comment: Please provide a Plunker example. From the provided information it's unclear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong property. The correct one is `this.element.nativeElement.offsetTop`

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is how you can get the active table and perform further operations accordingly:

1. Supposing that you top nav bar has id `navBar`, get the navBar element:

   > `@ViewChild('navBar') navBar: ElementRef;`
2. Get the tables, lets say with ids `tableOne` and `tableTwo`:

   > ```
   > @ViewChild('tableOne') tableOne: ElementRef;
   > @ViewChild('tableTwo') tableTwo: ElementRef;
   > ```
3. Here is a function that will return the visible table reference:

   > ```
   > getVisibleTable(): ElementRef
   > {
   >     let visibleTable: ElementRef = null;
   >     const navBarHeight = this.navBar.nativeElement.height;
   >     const tableOneTopOffset = this.tableOne.nativeElement.offsetTop;
   >     const tableTwoTopOffset = this.tableOne.nativeElement.offsetTop;
   >
   >     if (tableOneTopOffset >= navBarHeight) 
   >     {
   >         visibleTable = this.tableOne;
   >     }
   >     else if (tableOneTopOffset < navBarHeight)
   >     {
   >         if (tableTwoTopOffset >= navBarHeight)
   >         {
   >             visibleTable = this.tableTwo;
   >         }
   >         else
   >         {
   >             visibleTable = null;
   >         }
   >     }
   >
   >     return visibleTable;
   >  }
   > ```

Comment: damn..that was stupid of me ..thanks a lot..that answered half of my question.Please ans how to know if the element has passed the top of the element so that the answer could be accepted

Comment: That should be easy if you think and apply thr correct logic :) Take the top element reference and get the current element reference, the rest should be simple if else...

Comment: yeah that's right. i understood,but its for others who reads this post in future :)

Comment: @vikk I have updated my answer with the sample code to get the visible table.